# Filter on Category for NUnit MSBuild tasks?

Tags: msbuild, nunit, continuous-integration, msbuild-task

I'm setting up a MSBuild project to run some NUnit test, using the [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

With these settings I'll be able to run the NUnit tests:

```
<Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <CreateItem Include="$(ProjectTestDir)\$(ClassLibraryOutputDirectory)\*.Tests.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestAssembly" />
    </CreateItem>
    <NUnit Assemblies="@(TestAssembly)" />
</Target>
```

... but how can i run only certain tests - say the ones with a specific Category? We've added different categories to our tests - some to run all the time, some to only run at a nightly build etc.

I don't see any settings allowing me to filter on this, or did I miss something? Surely some of you have had this same problem and solved it somehow? It doesn't have to be using this msbuild community tasks project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking in the CHM, there's an IncludeCategory property... sounds like what you're looking for? (The CHM file is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks)

Comment: Perfect! I knew i was missing something - i was looking for documentation, but there it was :)

Comment: How can I apply this for TFS 2012 build server and NUnit tests? Should I decorate the tests with `Category("IntegrationTest")` attribute (as opposed `TestCategory("IntegrationTest")` attribute for MSTests) and then the `Test case Filter` of `TestCategory!=IntegrationTest` should filter the NUnit ones? Bonus: how to do that with xUnit tests? I don't see any category attributes.

Comment: @CsabaToth For xunit, there is a `TraitAttribute` and the `xunit` MSBuild task allows filtering on it via a Property AFAIK (I personally use the console runner, and it has a `/-trait` option in its commandline syntax). I won't guess (or pollute my mind!) by googling the MSTest equivalent for you. (BTW `TraitAttribute` is not `sealed` so it's common to roll appropriate attributes with known Keys (and values))

Comment: Thanks @RubenBartelink, that's a good trace to start on. Now the only question remains: does the xUnit Test Adapter implement `ITestCaseFilterExpression` (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx), so when I filter tests like this http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/07/ignore-test-categories-in-tfs-build-server-using-defaulttemplate-xaml/ the filtering would work?

Comment: @CsabaToth Unfortunately, it's not yet supported, see https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9835 (and go vote!)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thanks for the info! I voted! It doesn't seem to be a big whop to implement it. NUnit has it already (although https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/13) and it has some Traits also internally.

Comment: @CsabaToth It's not, but V2 work is being deliberately planned - there are lots of big ticket items like generalized fixture management and parallel running of tests which will go in first. For example, v2 doesnt run V1 tests yet (it'll need a shim), and it's hard to prioritise filtering in that context. See https://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=backlog https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/440213 In the meantime, why not rebase the cited PR onto 1.x or recompile 2.x if it's important to you?

Comment: Oh, you mean this: https://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/terje2000/TerjeTFS/contribution/3759 . It's really like the NUnit implementation!

Comment: @CsabaToth That's fine, but getting big V2 stuff should still take precendence IMO. Best to have this discussion over on xunit.xodeplex.com though - it just doesnt belong on a question or answer here