# How to Exclude a test from running using VS2012, TFS Build and NUnit

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

I have the following setup
Visual studio 2012 Update 2
NUnit Test Adapter Beta 4 
NUnit 2.62

I mark a test with either of the following attributes  Category from NUnit or TestCategory from MSTest:

```
[Category("WebServer")]
public void FooTest() {
 //test
}


[TestCategory("WebServer")]
public void FooTest2() {
 //test
}
```

In the TFS Build Template, I Set the property

1. Basic -> 1. Test Source -> Test Case Filter to the value:  **TestCategory!=WebServer**

When the build executes NO TESTS execute.  Removing the Filter and all tests run again.

The output from the build log is

*No test is available in C:\Builds\2\Proj\Build\bin\Debug\Tests.Integration.dll C:\Builds\2\Proj\Build\bin\Debug\Tests.Unit.dll C:\Builds\2\Proj\Build\bin\Debug\Tests.Web.dll C:\Builds\2\Proj\Build\bin\Debug\TestStack.BDDfy.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.*

Any clues how I can get a test to be excluded base on Category name?
I can easily verify the attribute works if I use the NUnit console runner.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026117/filter-on-category-for-nunit-msbuild-tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/ff3877ba-f064-4b5f-9c67-ab4adb6f0071) it would appear that you cannot use the TestCategory filters on NUnit tests, only on MSTest tests.

As a note, it would also appear that you are changing the property on the TFS Build Definition, not the Build Template. This is what I would expect, as changing the build definition would be the wrong place to change this.

Answer (score 3):

When using [NUnit Test Adapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/1.2.0) v1.1+, test Categories can be used on TFSBuild. You just need to install the package with your Test Project, and configure test case filter on your build definition.

Comment: Thanks emp, good to know that works now for TFS.  We've since moved to TeamCity from TFS and got it resolved shortly after.

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old question as this was one of the first results Google returned.

From [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-adapter/issues/18) it would seem that this was a bug that has been fixed in version 1.1, which unfortunately (as of 22 Jan 2014) has not yet been released to nuget